# WCF Service in Azure with ClaimsIdentity over SSL

Tags: .net, wcf, azure, wif

Created a WCF service as a WebRole using Azure and a client windows application which refers to this service. The Cloud Service is refered to a certificate which is created using the "Hands On Lab" given in windows identity foundation. The Web Service is hosted in IIS and it works perfect when executed.

I've created a client windows app which refers to this web service. Since WIF Claims identity is used, I have a claimsAuthorizationManager Class, and also a Policy class with set of defilned policies. The Claims is set in the web.config file.

When I execute the windows app as the start up project, the app prompts for authentication, and when the account credentials are given as in the config file, it opens a new "Windows Card Space" Window and Says "Incoming Policy Failed". When I close the window the System throws and Exception

The incoming policy could not be validated. For more information, please see the event log.

Event Log Details

Incoming policy failed validation.  No valid claim elements were found in the policy XML.

Additional Information:
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at Microsoft.InfoCards.Diagnostics.InfoCardTrace.BuildMessage(InfoCardBaseException ie)
   at Microsoft.InfoCards.Diagnostics.InfoCardTrace.TraceAndLogException(Exception e)
   at Microsoft.InfoCards.Diagnostics.InfoCardTrace.ThrowHelperError(Exception e)
   at Microsoft.InfoCards.InfoCardPolicy.Validate()
   at Microsoft.InfoCards.Request.PreProcessRequest()
   at Microsoft.InfoCards.ClientUIRequest.PreProcessRequest()
   at Microsoft.InfoCards.Request.DoProcessRequest(String& extendedMessage)
   at Microsoft.InfoCards.RequestFactory.ProcessNewRequest(Int32 parentRequestHandle, IntPtr rpcHandle, IntPtr inArgs, IntPtr& outArgs)

Details:

- System

  - Provider

  [ Name]  CardSpace 3.0.0.0

  - EventID 267

  [ Qualifiers]  49157

  Level 2

  Task 1

  Keywords 0x80000000000000

  EventRecordID 6996

  Channel Application
- EventData

  No valid claim elements were found in the policy XML. Additional Information: at System.Environment.get_StackTrace() at Microsoft.InfoCards.Diagnostics.InfoCardTrace.BuildMessage(InfoCardBaseException ie) at Microsoft.InfoCards.Diagnostics.InfoCardTrace.TraceAndLogException(Exception e) at Microsoft.InfoCards.Diagnostics.InfoCardTrace.ThrowHelperError(Exception e) at Microsoft.InfoCards.InfoCardPolicy.Validate() at Microsoft.InfoCards.Request.PreProcessRequest() at Microsoft.InfoCards.ClientUIRequest.PreProcessRequest() at Microsoft.InfoCards.Request.DoProcessRequest(String& extendedMessage) at Microsoft.InfoCards.RequestFactory.ProcessNewRequest(Int32 parentRequestHandle, IntPtr rpcHandle, IntPtr inArgs, IntPtr& outArgs)

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful to see your client app.config file. Also, what Hands o lab are you referring to? (e.g. Identity Training Kit?)